# Magnolia CMS: How to hide page in horizontal navigation bar at the top of my website

Tags: magnolia

I found something about this saying:
"In the General/Page properties window: “You may hide a page in the navigation by selecting 'Do not show this page in the navigation'."

Unfortunately I haven't got this option appearing.

Any idea how to do this some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adrien,

All of the STK page types should have a "Page Info" button in the top-right corner, which will open a dialog that has a "Hide in Navigation" checkbox.

If you're not using the STK pages, or those dialogs have been altered, it's possible to add the necessary property to hide a page in the navigation anyway using the JCR Browser. (The checkbox in the dialog is just another way of setting this value.)

Here's an example:

[image: Hiding the About page in the Demo Site]

To add this, just go to Tools -> JCR Browser, find the page you want to hide, click on it, click "New Node Data", and alter the fields to match what I've shown here: name "hideInNav", value "false".

Comment: Thanks Sean, I found out a couple of hours ago but wasn't allowed to reply to my own question :)